# installing packages without sudo access

Tags: installation, aptitude, dpkg, packages

Is there an easy way to install packages with a large dependency tree, provided that you don't have superuser access? For instance, say I wanted to install firefox. Firefox has a ton of dependencies, each of which have their own dependencies, etc. Installing these the "./configure; make; make install" way would take forever.

Is there an option I can give apt-get to make it install in a personal directory? Or is there a way to hack it to do all the heavy lifting for me?

Comment: try asking on www.superuser.com or if a server question specifically www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 4):

You can install individual .deb files in your home directory with:

```
dpkg-deb -x /path/to/some.deb $HOME
```

But this does not take care of the dependencies like aptitude or apt-get does.

Comment: I used this method to install atom for julia on my workstation. Additionally, I made an alias for atom in ~/.bashrc: alias atom="/path/to/the/executable/atom/binary/file". Then run: source ~/.bashrc, you are ready to run atom in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [NixOs](http://nixos.org/) ([LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/337677/)). Packages are isolated (sometimes the distribution needs to patch them) and can be installed several times, at different versions, or by different users.

[jhbuild](http://live.gnome.org/Jhbuild) can automate a big cmmi process. But someone needs to write a moduleset (a dependency graph).

If you're going with the manual configure/make all install process, it is possible to use [stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual.html) to simplify installing things in your home. Stow is helpful to install things in several prefixes but use only one prefix for dependency resolution.

dpkg can be coerced to install in a different prefix with instdir/admindir/root, but this is only useful for chroot environments.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a tool for that that i just made today
https://github.com/z3r0n3t/pkget All you need is access to bash no root are anything special You can use whet to download it as a zip file or use git clone
Really hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile Firefox from source, just install a binary package into your home directory.

[This](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Installing+Firefox+on+Linux) Mozilla KnowledgeBase article explains how to do it. Basically you need to just extract a [tarball](http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-3.6&os=linux&lang=en-US) and execute a `firefox` file in it; all dependencies are already included so you don't need to install anything with `apt`.

**EDIT:** No, there is no generic method exists, at least because most applications (and especially GUI ones) require much of it's associated data to be placed in well known locations like /usr/share, and it is *hardcoded* in it (well, it can be configured at compile time, but you don't want to recompile everything as you said in question). So you just can check for pre-compiled binary packages that search for resources in launch directory and not system ones.

Comment: i interpret the question to be about package management practices.  i suspect Firefox is just an example, so Firefox-specific methods aren't overly useful.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post. Firefox info is still useful through.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty much "no".  First of all the package database is only accessible by root, and secondly, some/many packages have hardcoded paths that make it impossible to relocate them.  Using a chroot would be a possible answer, but you also need root for that, or at least someone with root to grant you limited rights.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do a chroot then you can install your packages there.

ref:
https://help.ubuntu.com/6.10/ubuntu/packagingguide/C/appendix-chroot.html
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot

Comment: root privileges are anyway required to create a chroot, so why don't just install packages *instead*?
Apart from this, chances that your sysadmin will grant you full root privileges (or even just apt-related) are much, much less than ones for chroot. It is (almost) not dangerous for host system.